# PHP returning HTML Tags along with JSON in WAMP

Tags: php, html, json, wamp

I want to return the values stored in a table in MySQL in the form of JSON. I wrote the below php code as below :-

json1.php

```
<?php

header('Content-type:application/json');

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db('testdb');

$select = mysql_query('select * from questions');

$rows = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{

    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

When I check this in my browser I get the following output :-

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\unit1\json1.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242216</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\unit1\json1.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\json1.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>242688</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\unit1\json1.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\json1.php<b>:</b>5</td></tr>
</table></font>
[{"0":"Test1","product":"Test1","1":"Hello","questions":"Hello"},{"0":"","product":"","1":"","questions":""},{"0":"Test1","product":"Test1","1":"Venky","questions":"Venky"},{"0":"","product":"","1":"","questions":""}]
```

As you see, the url return the json along with a bunch of html tags. I don't want this. I just want the json to be returned.

I am using Windows 7 with WAMP Server. I have put my php file in the directory "C:\wamp\www\unit1". Strangely enough when I use the same php file in my MAC with MAMP Server the output (in the browser) is just the json string(exactly the way I want it).

Can you please help me figure out what is wrong with my windows system ? Is there a way to just return the json string (without the html tags) from WAMP ?

Please help.

Comment: Those are debug messages along with the JSON output.

Comment: Just read the messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you even read the warning?

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Tells you exactly what is wrong, you're using mysql_* functions, which are deprecated, switch to mysqli prepared statements or PDO instead.

Links to Documentation: [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 3):

You have error display enabled in your php settings, that is wrong.

Usually those warnings would therefore be shown in a browser window as readable text. This might not work in case you sent the result as json content type.

Disable the display of errors in the output sent and just log it to a logfile instead. that makes much more sense and does not break your output. You can make that adjustment in your php configuration, typically in the central `php.ini` file.

The reason why you get errors (or warnings in this case) simply is that something is wrong with your php code. You are using an outdated and deprecated mysql connection driver. Switch to a newer one like mysqli (or PDO) to prevent security issues. Read about the advantages of "prepared statements" for this, too.

Answer (score 2):

This tripped me up for a while too. It seems 'display errors' is set to 'on' as default when you install wamp. It was for me anyways. I think when your new to PHP, and the tools you use when developing with PHP (like I am), silly problems like this can be frustrating. It's hard to find the right answer when you don't even know the right question yet.

So in case any other noobs (like me) are searching this:

in your task bar, click on the wamp notification icon.

select PHP/PHP settings and uncheck the 'display errors' setting.

as was said earlier, you should send your errors to a log file instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

- Installed and enabled Xdebug
- Set html_errors to `on`

Answer (score -1):

Disable deprecated notices - put this code at the beginning of your php file

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: Don't disable warnings, fix them.